# PowerShell or Batch file to report whether a file exists on remote computers

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I am looking for a batch file or PowerShell script to run on remote machines, to check if a file exists, and if it doesn't, report it to .txt or .cvs file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Test-Path` and `Add-Content` cmdlets to achieve this. Here's a simple, generic example. You can update it to reflect your specific needs.

```
# Step 1: Build an array of file paths
$FileList = @(
      '\\computer1\c$\path\to\file.txt'
    , '\\computer2\share\file\name.ext'
    , '\\computer3\path\to\foo\bar.txt'
    )

# Step 2: Test each path and log to a text file
foreach ($File in $FileList) {
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $File)) {
        Add-Content -Path 'c:\path\to\log file.log' -Value "File does not exist: $File";
    }
}
```

To import a list of computers, use the `Get-Content` cmdlet:

```
# Step 1: Get array of computer names and define path
$ComputerList = Get-Content -Path c:\list\of\computers.txt;
$FilePath = '\\{0}\share\path\to\file.txt';

# Step 2: Test each path and log to a text file
foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList) {
    if (!(Test-Path -Path ($FilePath -f $Computer))) {
        Add-Content -Path 'c:\path\to\log file.log' -Value "File does not exist: $File";
    }
}
```

Comment: I have list of computers, I dont have to go one by one. Can i import it from a txt file?

Comment: I have added an example of how to import a list of computers and test a static file path on each one.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make a file accessible. I will assume that, for security reasons, you don't want to give access to the file, only detect if the file is there. In this case I would use a simple HTTP server running on the remote machines and test it using curl or wget. There are equivalents for Windows.

If you do want to access the file content then I would make the folder public and use the test-path: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx

Comment: I installed a software on few remote machines but users are complaining that its not working. so i wanted to check if the files /folder exists if not i have to manually run it. Thanks.